# comp_cd > to_char('0000000000','9999999999')

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have come across an SQL statement where one of the conditions is `comp_cd > to_char('0000000000','9999999999')`.

Running `select to_char('0000000000','9999999999') from dual` i am getting the result "0".

Does anyone has come across this?

Comment: What results did you expect?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) is your friend... This looks like a zero-padding mechanism to compare `comp_cd` pseudo-numerically despite it (I assume) being a fixed-width string for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `TO_CHAR` expects a NUMBER or DATE as its first parameter, but you're providing a string (`'0000000000'`) instead.

Therefore, Oracle uses an implicit conversion to convert it to a NUMBER first; `'0000000000'` is converted to the number `0`.

Then, TO_CHAR converts `0` back to a string using the `'9999999999'` format model. This should result in the string:

```
'          0'
```

Finally:

```
comp_cd > '          0'
```

would do a lexical (alphabetical) comparison between two strings.